# Add "not" to if statement in shell script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have the following script that should exist if the user does not exist.

```
#check if user currently exists on system
if id $User > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    #user exists no need to exit program
    echo "blah blah, what a waste of space"
else
    echo "This user does NOT exists.  Please create that user before using this script.\n"
    exit
fi
```

My problem is that I would ideally like to place a "not" if that first if statement so that I can trim down my if, else statement.  Ideally I would like something like this:

```
if !(id $User > /dev/null 2>&1)
then
    echo "This user does NOT exists.  Please create that user before using this script.\n"
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Not” is spelled `!`, with no punctuation and a space after it.

```
if ! id "$user_name" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo 1>&2 "This user does NOT exists.  Please create that user before using this script.\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

Your proposal would actually work, but the parentheses create a subshell to run the one command `id`, which is superfluous.

Other changes:

- Always put double quotes around variable substitutions: `"$user_name"`
- There is already a variable `USER`, which is the name of the current logged-in user. Variable names are case-sensitive, but humans not so much.
- Return a value between 1 and 125 to indicate failure in a program.
- Report errors to standard error (file descriptor 2), not standard output.

Comment: Ah, I was so close.  I tried it with the ! but placed it at the end.  Thanks for the extra info too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *not* operator in shell scripting, and it is `!`, but you're not using it quite correctly.

Put a space between the `!` operator and its operand, and leave out the parentheses. This should work for all [POSIX-style shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), including `bash` and `sh`/`dash`.

```
if ! id $User > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "This user does NOT exists.  Please create that user before using this script.\n"
    exit
fi
```

You can use parentheses for grouping if you like, though it is not necessary in this case. A new subshell is created to execute the parenthesized expression. The `!` operator should still have a space between it and the `(` character. (Spaces around the parentheses themselves is optional.)

```
if ! (id $User > /dev/null 2>&1)
then
    echo "This user does NOT exists.  Please create that user before using this script.\n"
    exit
fi
```

See [Gilles's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/345273/22949), for some good alternatives and style recommendations. (Also, thanks to Gilles for some corrections about the use of parentheses.)

Comment: Spaces are not necessary around parentheses. (They are necessary around braces and brackets, however. No, I don't know why.) Parentheses to create subshells work in all Bourne-style shells.

Comment: @Gilles You're right. I have now corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this one get answered in "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide"
 - which is viewable and available for download at http://www.tldp.org/guides.html